# What does this do in my routes.rb file?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am looking at a gist showing me how to handle CORS request in a Rails app.  My routes.rb needs to have this bit of code in it.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    controller :whatever, path: '/whatever' do
        match 'post_action', via: [ :post, :options]
    end
end
```

If I was looking at a `post` resource, could someone show me how to set this up?  I mainly do not understand the `match` function.

Answer (score 0):

It will match the /whatever/post_action with the Controller/Action whatever#post_action. One useful tool you could use to see what your routes.rb are doing is to run the command:

```
rake routes
```

That will display all the routing table of your Rails app.

You can find more info in the Rails guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Take care!

Answer (score 0):

Actually **match** is not the good way to handle routes. 
In rails 4 also it removed.

You can use the following code to use it:-

```html
resource :whatever do
  post 'post_action'
end
```

To test your routes

```html
rake routes
```